# multiscreen app content

Tags: android, setattribute, multiscreen

I have a multiscreen app that is up and running and you can press four buttons.One to list phone numbers one to list dinning halls one to list residence halls and one for academic buildings.

[image: Here is what the listview looks like]

Comment: Generally this kind of question would be closed, being considered too broad or one that "does not show research effort". However, you seem to be doing well, designing your app well, and I know how hard things can be when you're not familiar with them, so I prefer to answer your question and also help you here. Be warned, however, that you should generally ask specific questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question very well.

You need different [`Activities`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html). Each one will be your new "screen".

You use each of those buttons to call each [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) using [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) objects.

Inside each activity you place a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) component. This `ListView` object will "list" (hence the name) multiple values.

This is an overview of Android (simplification). You don't seem to know much about [Android fundamentals in general](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html), so my advice is to research each of the above components using Google and the Android Dev Guide. And, of course, StackOverflow.

---

> My question is one each page how would I list multiple entries?
>
> For example if i wanted to list 10 phone numbers on that page.

As I said, create a "page" (`Activity`) with a `ListView` inside it. To populate the ListView with values (your phone numbers), see [this guide](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views) (see 'List Views' in the middle of the page). To work with the item that the user selected in the list, provide the `onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)`.

The guide above shows how to do that.

Comment: umm I already made all the activities and XMLS already and they jump from page to page. The bottom button is a dialer and works and the other bottom button launches the web browser. is there any import statements or anything else that I need to add to that?

Comment: I updated the answer. Now, ask an specific question. What do you want to do exactly. I know your dialer works, I want to know what you want to do. What does NOT work.

Comment: ok so what I want to do is i have separate java pages created for each button. Each one of those pages have content in them. What I want to do is where there is the dining halls I want to list multiple lines of content with out using a text view

Comment: "where there is the dining halls I want to list multiple lines of content with out using a text view" --- As I said, use a ListView. What in the ListView implementation you couldn't do?

Comment: I got the list view to work,can u put multiple lines per each entry in the list view, So you would have the dinning hall and then the hours listed in one entry and then the same for the next entry

Comment: Yes, you can. If you saw the guide, you'll see that the ListView items are built using an ArrayAdapter<String> using a layout called simple_list_item_1. The ArrayAdapter "plugs" the strings into that layout (that layout is just a TextView, as you can see). You need to build your own custom layout and custom adapter (you'll need to extend it, most people extend BaseAdapter). See this example: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ This was the first example that helped me back then. ;-)

Comment: Android also provides a ready-to-use layout. I think it's called "two_line_list_item" or something like that. Type android.R.Layout. and wait until code completion goes. You'll see... but you'll still need to change the way the adapter work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all your help man! I got the all whole app working with all the different activities and buttons working.I never took java and I am in the android app development class at school so ive been learning as ive going